# Update the record of DE in the cloud page with Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The problem is that I need to click a button to update the recommendation code field of DE's record to determine whether the user has a recommendation code. If not, update it, and the recommendation code of each user cannot be repeated. If I do this, I will have the problem of duplicate recommendation codes. How should I change the code?
Ampscript：

```
if RequestParameter("submitted_referral") == true and (Lookup("personal information","CountryCode","CountryCode", RequestParameter("countryCode_referral")) == RequestParameter("countryCode_referral") and Lookup("personal information","Telephone","Telephone", RequestParameter("telephone_referral")) == RequestParameter("telephone_referral")) then
  var @ReferralCode,@rows, @rowCount
  set @rows = LookupRows("personal information","ReferralCode", " ")
  set @rowCount = format(Add(Subtract(DataExtensionRowCount("personal information"),rowcount(@rows)),1),"000000")
  UpdateData("personal information",1,
  "Telephone",RequestParameter("telephone_referral"),"ReferralCode", @rowCount)
endif
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure that I get your problem. But it sounds to me like a coupon code logic could work for you with ClaimRow. https://sprignaturemoves.com/coupon-claiming-in-ampscript/

Comment: I can't recall using ClaimRow() the way DonL is recommending, but it should work. If not, my approach would be using 2 pages. Visitor clicks on button in page 1 - sends them to page 2 that has code evaluating if subscriber has a recommendation code. If they do, redirect them back to page 1 - if they don't, run the UpdateData() function on page 2 - add the recommendation code, then redirect them back to page 1. This can all probably be done more elegantly with AJAX and SSJS in one page.

Comment: In fact, what I want to ask is how to obtain a set of non-duplicate recommendation codes. Just like the ID of each user, my requirement is that the recommendation code needs to be 6 numbers and each user's is non-duplicate, and after deleting a user's record, it will not cause the appearance of duplicate recommendation codes. However, my above ampscript code will have duplicate recommendation codes.